# Request for All Google IMAP IP Subnets

Tags: imap

I need to know all of Google's IMAP subnet addresses so I can allow bidirectional traffic on my company's firewall between ALL of Google's IMAP subnets and a specific internal client.

I've executed the command `nslookup imap.gmail.com` and received the following IP addresses in the results:

```
108.177.122.108
108.177.122.109
74.125.21.108
74.125.21.109
74.125.136.108
74.125.136.109
```

I want to make sure that I don't miss any IP addresses/subnets when I create the firewall rule on my company's firewall.

Comment: It is unlikely you can get a full list.  The DNS is region-specific, and it changes fairly frequently as google adds or drops servers, changes data center routing, etc.  Secondly, this is not a promising question, so is off-topic,  this question, if it can be answered at all should be on our sister site, serverfault

Comment: What you want is available from the BGP announcements, see https://bgp.he.net/AS15169#_prefixes and https://bgp.he.net/AS15169#_prefixes6

Comment: i cant; edit it now, but I meant "not a programming question".  "promising" is not the judgement I wanted to make.